# Can I create a new file, and open it in a new tab in a single command?

Tags: vim

Simple question, with Vim can I create a new file, and open it in a new tab in one command?

At the moment I am:

- `:new` to create a new file
- `:tab split` to get this file into a new tab
- `:tabp` to go back to the previous tab
- `:q` to close the other instance of the file
- `:tabn` to go to my new file

Bit of a mouthful for what would in other text editors be a single action, is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
:tabe[dit] {filename}
```

Of course, `{filename}` can also be an existing file.